# is there a method to delete the element at the end of a doubly linked list?

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

Hi I would like to implement a doubly chained list with 4 operations namely:

- 'push' (*insert value at back*);
- 'pop' (*remove value at back*);
- 'shift' (*remove value at front*).
- 'unshift' (*insert value at front*);

I was able to implement them, but I have a mistake when I do unit tests on the different methods. my shift method that is supposed to delete the item at the end of the list returns an error to me when running unit tests
Here is my source code.
here the class of Doubly linked list

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, succeeding=None, previous=None):
        # reference to next node into the doubly linked list 
        self.next = succeeding
        # reference to previous node into the doubly linked list
        self.prev = previous
        # adding an value element to the node
        self.data = value

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    
    def push(self, new_data):
        """ insert value at back in the list
        Args:
            new_data (object): the value to insert at the back in the list
        Returns:
            None
        """
        # creating a new node with the desired value
        new_node = Node(new_data) 
         # newly created node's next pointer will refer to the old head
        new_node.next = self.head
        # Checks whether list is empty or not
        if self.head != None: 
            # old head's previous pointer will refer to newly created node
            self.head.prev = new_node 
            # new node becomes the new head
            self.head = new_node 
            new_node.prev = None
        
        else: # If the list is empty, make new node both head and tail
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            new_node.prev = None # There's only one element so both pointers refer to null

    def unshift(self, new_data):
        """ Insert value at front in the list
        Args:
            new_data (object): the value to insert at the front in the list
        Returns:
            None
        """
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.prev = self.tail
        # checks whether the list is empty, if so make both head and tail as new node
        if self.tail == None: 
            self.head = new_node 
            self.tail = new_node
            # the first element's previous pointer has to refer to null
            new_node.next = None 
        # If list is not empty, change pointers accordingly        
        else: 
            self.tail.next = new_node
            new_node.next = None
            self.tail = new_node # Make new node the new tail

    def pop(self): 
        """ Remove value at back in the list
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            data (object): The value removed at the back in the list
        """            
        if self.head == None:
            print("List is empty")

        else:
            temp = self.head
#            temp.next.prev = None # remove previous pointer referring to old head
            self.head = temp.next # make second element the new head
            temp.next = None # remove next pointer referring to new head
            return temp.data
  
    def shift(self): 
        """ Remove value at front in the list
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            data (object): The value removed at the front in the list
        """                  
        if self.tail == None:
            print("List is empty")

        else:
            temp = self.tail
            # temp.prev.next = None # removes next pointer referring to old tail
            self.tail = temp.prev # make second to last element the new tail
            temp.prev = None # remove previous pointer referring to new tail
            return temp.data
    
    def taille(self, dll):
        """ Get the length of the doubly linked list
        Args:
            dll (Object): the doubly linked list
        Returns:
            length (list): The length of the DLL
        """
        n = 0
        lst = dll
        while lst is not None:
            n = n + 1
            lst = lst.next
        return n
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.taille(self.head)
    
    
    # This function prints contents of linked list
    # starting from the given node
    def printList(self, node):
        print("\nTraversal in forward direction")
        while node:
            print(" {}".format(node.data), end="")
            last = node
            node = node.next
    
# Start with empty list
if __name__ == "__main__":
    llist = LinkedList()
    # Insert 6. So the list becomes 6->None
    llist.unshift(6)

    # Insert 7 at the beginning.
    # So linked list becomes 7->6->None
    llist.push(7)

    # Insert 1 at the beginning.
    # So linked list becomes 1->7->6->None
    llist.push(1)

    # Insert 4 at the end.
    # So linked list becomes 1->7->6->4->None
    llist.unshift(4)
    print("Created DLL is: ")
    llist.printList(llist.head)
    print('\n', len(llist))
    
    print('shift value return ',llist.shift())
    print('pop value return ',llist.pop())
    print("\n List after pop/shift element: ")
    llist.printList(llist.head)
    # print('\n', len(llist))
```

here is the test case

```
import unittest

from linked_list import LinkedList


class LinkedListTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_push_pop(self):
        lst = LinkedList()
        lst.push(10)
        lst.push(20)
        self.assertEqual(lst.pop(), 20)
        self.assertEqual(lst.pop(), 10)

    def test_push_shift(self):
        lst = LinkedList()
        lst.push(10)
        lst.push(20)
        self.assertEqual(lst.shift(), 10)
        self.assertEqual(lst.shift(), 20)

    def test_unshift_shift(self):
        lst = LinkedList()
        lst.unshift(10)
        lst.unshift(20)
        self.assertEqual(lst.shift(), 20)
        self.assertEqual(lst.shift(), 10)

    def test_unshift_pop(self):
        lst = LinkedList()
        lst.unshift(10)
        lst.unshift(20)
        self.assertEqual(lst.pop(), 10)
        self.assertEqual(lst.pop(), 20)

    def test_all(self):
        lst = LinkedList()
        lst.push(10)
        lst.push(20)
        self.assertEqual(lst.pop(), 20)
        lst.push(30)
        self.assertEqual(lst.shift(), 10)
        lst.unshift(40)
        lst.push(50)
        self.assertEqual(lst.shift(), 40)
        self.assertEqual(lst.pop(), 50)
        self.assertEqual(lst.shift(), 30)

    def test_length(self):
        lst = LinkedList()
        lst.push(10)
        lst.push(20)
        self.assertEqual(len(lst), 2)
        lst.shift()
        self.assertEqual(len(lst), 1)
        lst.pop()
        self.assertEqual(len(lst), 0)

    def test_iterator(self):
        lst = LinkedList()
        lst.push(10)
        lst.push(20)
        iterator = iter(lst)
        self.assertEqual(next(iterator), 10)
        self.assertEqual(next(iterator), 20)




    def supprime(self):
        self.supprimeCellule(self.head, 1)
    
    def supprimeCellule(self, L, n):
        """ Supprime la cellule après la nième cellule dans la liste L"""
        if n > self.taille(L)-1:
            raise IndexError("Indice invalide")
        for i in range(n-1):
            L = L.next
            L.next = L.next.next

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have this error:

```
.EF....
======================================================================
ERROR: test_iterator (__main__.LinkedListTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\guera\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\preludd-recrutement-overlap\linked-list\linked_list_test.py", line 62, in test_iterator
    iterator = iter(lst)
TypeError: 'LinkedList' object is not iterable

======================================================================
FAIL: test_length (__main__.LinkedListTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\guera\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\preludd-recrutement-overlap\linked-list\linked_list_test.py", line 54, in test_length
    self.assertEqual(len(lst), 1)
AssertionError: 2 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your `shift` and `pop` method lack logic for:

- clearing the link **to** the removed node, or
- when the list becomes empty, to clear *both* the `head` and `tail` attributes

So, for `pop` you have to add this in the `else` block

```
            if self.head:
                self.head.prev = None
            else:
                self.tail = None
```

...and similarly, this for `shift`:

```
            if self.tail:
                self.tail.next = None
            else:
                self.head = None
```

As a side note: I would have interpreted the functioning of your methods to be opposite: the comment for `pop` says *"Remove value **at back** in the list". To me, the *back* of the list is where `tail` points to, and the *front* of the list is where `head` points to. But your interpretation works for you, it is fine. It just will differ when performing an iteration over the list.

Comment: Hi, you were absolutely right I reversed everything, and at the level of the iteration test it was bugging. I turned everything around and it works well. I overloaded the iter() and next() methods in order to adapt them to my chained list.